# C++ returning array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to wrap my mind around arrays and pointers in C++.

I am trying to write a function that allocates memory for an `int` array of variable size. The array is then filled with random numbers and returned.

The problem I have is assigning values with pointers.

This is the function:

```
int* getArray(int length) {
    int* values = new int[length];
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        values[i]=i;
    }
    return values;
}
```

And it works just fine.

But, if I change it to this:

```
int* getArray(int length) {
    int* values = new int[length];
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++, values ++) {
        *values=i;
    }
    return values;
}
```

It doesn't work.

Can someone explain to me why I cannot do this?

This is the `main` method that I used to print all the values:

```
int main() {
    int* v = getArray(100);
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++, v++) {
        cout << *v <<endl;
    }
    delete[] v;
    return 0;
}
```

I think it is because the `new` operator allocates new memory in the heap and not in the stack so the pointer might actually point to the wrong direction.

But, if that is true, why is the `main` method working?

Side note: I do not get any kind of warning or error, but the output is just a bunch of zeros and some random numbers.

I am using the GCC compiler on Ubuntu.

Comment: An array is represented by a pointer to its first element. In your second example you don't return a pointer to the first element.

Comment: Once you figure things out, ditch what you have learned and use `std::vector` instead, then all these problems will go away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`values++` is modifying `values`, which eventually forms the function return value.

i.e. you return one past the end of the allocated array. That in itself is perfectly legal C++.

But things go very badly wrong at the function call site: you access invalid elements of the array (which very informally speaking are your "random numbers"), and calling `delete[]` on that is also undefined behaviour. **Boom!**

Comment: To be clear, the pointer value you `delete[]` must be *exactly* what was returned by `new []`, or undefined behavior results. Whether it's pointing past the end or at the second element, **Boom!**